# Stop event of ecm.widget.dialog.ConfirmationDialog

Tags: dojo, ibm-content-navigator

I'm using `ecm.widget.dialog.ConfirmationDialog` and have added a `dijit/SimpleTextArea` to it. On click of Yes button, I'm checking if there is a value entered by a user in the `textarea` and if not, I want to show a message to user and stay on the `confirmationDialog`. It shows the message but event is getting fired and flow continues. I even tried to stop the event by

```
dojo.stopEvent(evt);
```

but it doesn't work. Can someone help me on how to stop that event so that dialog is retained until the user enters a value?

Below is the code snippet

```
this.msgDialogBox = new ConfirmationDialog();
var textarea = new SimpleTextarea({
                    rows: "4",
                    cols: "50",
                    placeHolder:"Please provide reject reason",
                    maxLength:"256",
                    style:"width: 95%; height: 90px;",
                    required:true
                },domConstruct.create("div",{align:'center'},this.msgDialogBox.contentArea));
textarea.startup();


on(this.msgDialogBox,"Execute",function(evt){

                    if(!textarea.get("value")){
                        domConstruct.place(domConstruct.create("div",{align:'center',innerHTML:'Reject reason cannot be blank',style:'color:#ff0000'}),this.inlineMessage,"after");
                        dojo.stopEvent(evt);

                    }else{
                        //value is there so perform task
                    }

                });
```

Comment: Try using `evt.stopPropagation()` instead of `dojo.stopEvent(evt)` and return from the the event handler after this.

Comment: Yes I did try it but no luck

Answer (score 0):

It's not really the event that causes the dialog to hide, but the onExectue itself.

The "dijit/Dialog" superclass of the ConfirmationDialog actually always adds a .hide() (through aspect.after) to the onExecute during postCreate just - before the .onExectue is linked to the 'ok' button. This makes it really hard to influence the function as the .hide is always executed after the onExecute.

I can think of two options:

1. Throw an exception in the onExecute to break the execution.
2. Create your own implementation of the BaseDialog. This would give you the complete freedom to create a button that uses your own function in which you can manually call the .hide - or not.

Obviously the first solution can't hardly be recommended, but it would work. The second would be a more elegant solution and would allow you to write prettier code as you can integrate the SimpleTextArea in your custom widget.